# Stack Overflow uses what webserver?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, architecture, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Which webserver does Stack Overflow use?

Comment: @c0mrade, please associate your accounts at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138604?tab=accounts

Comment: random you edited my question. I didn't write the second part of it, you should write something if you were editing my original question content

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow use a MSSQL, dotnet architecture.

Comment: what about webserver? light http -> my guess ..

Comment: Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0

Answer (score 0):

From the HTTP response:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
```

Comment: ty, how come does it work so fast using IIS?

Comment: Dedicated server, optimized database scheme, properly coded backend?

Comment: You're probably right thank you

Comment: (Or they manually set the `Server` field and secretly run something else, but I don't find that so likely.)

Comment: Also, you should associate your accounts and take ownership of this question (see the "accounts" tab in your profile).

Answer (score 0):

Meta stack overflow runs on iis 7.0, asp.net mvc, ms sql.

Comment: how on earth can you run on jQuery?

Comment: @Olafur Waage What? Are you asking that because somebody thought that the server was run on JQuery? Or, are you actually questioning the incredible undeniable greatness of JQuery?